# Need to run java under wine and ie in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, wine

my bank wants ie and java

Comment: *waits for an actual question. Please treat the community with respect.

Comment: Just earned "Popular Question" for this

Answer (score 1):

java is already present in ubuntu,check synaptic

you'll need wine for IE only

there's a add-on for firefox that reports the browser as being an IE,I just don't remember the name

Answer (score 0):

Get a new bank - and tell your current one why you are moving.

Alternatively, you could, if you are using Firefox, [pretend to be using IE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/). I assume that there are similar tools for other browsers if necessary, I definitely remember this being built into Opera many years ago.

Comment: I'd feel a little wrong upvoting this because "get a new bank" is not exactly a practical solution - but on the other hand, I agree completely that it'd be an appropriate course of action in this situation.